# PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver - find reason that org.springframework.core.io.Resource is set to "file:/" for certain jar

Tags: java, spring, classpath

I have some code below that is being used to scan for my batis mapper files.  I'm scanning for a My Batis file, but I think my problem is more a Spring issue.

The code listed has been working fine, but when I add dependency to certain external library that is stored in my local maven repo, the PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.getResources() method returns a resource of "file:/" for a specific jar.  This is causing spring to search my entire C drive for mapper files.

I was able to determine what jar is causing this behavior but I'm not sure what the resolution is. Why is Spring setting the  Resource to "file:/" ?  I'm not sure what is wrong with this jar vs others that return a normal resource entry.

> ```
> SqlSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new SqlSessionFactoryBean();
> PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver patternResolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver();
> Resource configLocation = patternResolver.getResource("classpath:mybatis/mybatis.config.xml");
>
>  //this line leads to the issue
> Resource[] mapperLocations1 = patternResolver.getResources("classpath*:**/*Mapper.xml");
> ```

[image]

```
//this is from the Spring PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver class
    protected Resource[] findPathMatchingResources(String locationPattern) throws IOException {
        String rootDirPath = determineRootDir(locationPattern);
        String subPattern = locationPattern.substring(rootDirPath.length());
        Resource[] rootDirResources = getResources(rootDirPath);
        Set<Resource> result = new LinkedHashSet<Resource>(16);
        for (Resource rootDirResource : rootDirResources) {
            rootDirResource = resolveRootDirResource(rootDirResource);
            URL rootDirUrl = rootDirResource.getURL();
            if (equinoxResolveMethod != null) {
                if (rootDirUrl.getProtocol().startsWith("bundle")) {
                    rootDirUrl = (URL) ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(equinoxResolveMethod, null, rootDirUrl);
                    rootDirResource = new UrlResource(rootDirUrl);
                }
            }
            if (rootDirUrl.getProtocol().startsWith(ResourceUtils.URL_PROTOCOL_VFS)) {
                result.addAll(VfsResourceMatchingDelegate.findMatchingResources(rootDirUrl, subPattern, getPathMatcher()));
            }
            else if (ResourceUtils.isJarURL(rootDirUrl) || isJarResource(rootDirResource)) {
                result.addAll(doFindPathMatchingJarResources(rootDirResource, rootDirUrl, subPattern));
            }
            else {
                result.addAll(doFindPathMatchingFileResources(rootDirResource, subPattern));
            }
        }
        if (logger.isDebugEnabled()) {
            logger.debug("Resolved location pattern [" + locationPattern + "] to resources " + result);
        }
        return result.toArray(new Resource[result.size()]);
```

Comment: What is `rootDirResources`?

Comment: added the class that generates rootDirResources.  Is is from the spring PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.findPathMatchingResources()method

Comment: Thank you for showing a lot of irrelevant information, now let's try some relevant information: You're asking why `file:/` is in `rootDirResources`. It is built by call to `getResources(rootDirPath)`, which we can't see, and it takes a `rootDirPath` argument. `rootDirPath` is built by call to `determineRootDir(locationPattern)`, which we also can't see, and it takes a `locationPattern` argument. `locationPattern` is a parameter, and we don't know its value. So, we have an unknown value, passed through two unknown methods, and you expect us to be able to tell you why the content is what it is?

Comment: Try **debugging** the code to see where the value comes from.